# Basic Google API Oauth2 Authentication Setup Fails To Give Objects?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

I have coded an authentication and I get an access token, but when I use it to grab an object I just end up getting `'NoneType' object is not callable`.

```
 Exception Location: googleads\adwords.py in GetService, line 365
 Exception Type: Type Error
 Exception Value: Internal Server Error: /oauth2callback
```

I get the same result whether calling for Customer or CampaignService. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I am following the code in [Googleads](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/create_adwords_client_with_access_token.py).

```
def getAdwordsFlow():
    FLOW.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/oauth2callback'

    # Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
    authorization_url, state = FLOW.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline',
        include_granted_scopes='true')
    return authorization_url


def getAdwordsTokens(request):
    auth_code = request.GET.get('code')
    FLOW.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
    credentials = FLOW.credentials

    oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleAccessTokenClient(
    FLOW.credentials.token, FLOW.credentials.expiry)

    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(
    "DEVELOPER-TOKEN", oauth2_client, "USER-AGENT", "CLIENT-CUSTOMER-ID")

    customer = adwords_client.GetService('CustomerService').getCustomers()[0]
    print('You are logged in as customer: %s' % customer['customerId'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^oauth2callback', queries.getAdwordsTokens, name='auth_calledback'),] #How
```

view.py

```
def index(request):
    return redirect(getAdwordsFlow())
```

Terminal output:

`"GET /oauth2callback?state=XXXXXXXXX&code=4/XXXXXXXXXXX&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email HTTP/1.1" 500 80213`
Why is it 500?

I notice my access token has a different value when I call for it. So I am assuming it's working.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, your service call is -

> GET /oauth2callback?state=XXXXXXXXX&code=4/XXXXXXXXXXX&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email HTTP/1.1

This call is neither get access token call nor having `access_token` in the request and as per your [reference](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/create_adwords_client_with_access_token.py) code it will generate `access_token` from `refresh_token`.

```
def main(access_token, token_expiry, client_customer_id, developer_token,
         user_agent):
  oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleAccessTokenClient(access_token, token_expiry)

  adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(
      developer_token, oauth2_client, user_agent,
      client_customer_id=client_customer_id)

  customer = adwords_client.GetService('CustomerService').getCustomers()[0]
  print 'You are logged in as customer: %s' % customer['customerId']


if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = parser.parse_args()

  # Retrieve a new access token for use in this example. In a production
  # application, you may use a credential store to share access tokens for a
  # given user across applications.
  oauth2credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
      None, args.client_id, args.client_secret, args.refresh_token,
      datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1, 12), GOOGLE_OAUTH2_ENDPOINT,
      USER_AGENT)

  oauth2credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())

  main(oauth2credentials.access_token, oauth2credentials.token_expiry,
       args.client_customer_id, args.developer_token, USER_AGENT)
```

So to use your code, first generate `refresh_token` using [this code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/generate_refresh_token.py) and then use it in your given code.